# Correct way of filtering datagrid using datatables in C# WPF

Tags: c#, datagrid, datatables

I am creating a WPF application. There is a `DataGrid` displaying my items and search bar to filter the data. As you know we can't have specific rows from a `Dataable` to be referenced from another datatable. So the way I'm filtering right now is cloning my original database and adding the rows which matches search bar text to the cloned datatable. After that setting the datagrid's `ItemsSource` to the cloned datatable to show the filtered rows.

Now the problem is that when I edit my datagrid with filtered rows then obviously that cloned datatable is being modified not the original datatable. So how can I make those changes in the original datatable as well ?

I tried referencing rows from original datatable but that's no possible as one `DataRow` in memory can have only one  container, the original datatable in this case.

**EDIT**

The answer was simple instead of using 2 `DataTable` use a `DataView` which is designed for this very purpose. See the modified code below.

My filter logic:

```
var filteredTable = dt.Clone();

foreach( DataRow row in dt.Rows)
{
    if(row[FilterCategory].ToString().StartsWith(txtb_search.Text))
    {
         filteredTable.Rows.Add(row.ItemArray);
    }
}

ItemsGrid.ItemsSource = filteredTable.DefaultView;
```

Comment: Why arent you using a DataView?

Comment: @NewContributor How naive of me that I didn't know about that. That  was exactly what I wanted.I will be posting an answer shortly with modified code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is how to do filtering the correct way using DataView. The `filter` string can have many forms depending on the requirement. `sortColumn` is `filterColumn` right now but can be any column to base sort on. Here is a quick tutorial to all this: http://www.csharp-examples.net/dataview-rowfilter/

```
 string filterColumn = dt.Columns[columnIndex].ToString();
 string filter = filterColumn + " LIKE '" + txtb_search.Text + "*'";

 DataView dv = new DataView(dt, filter, sortColumn , DataViewRowState.CurrentRows);
 ItemsGrid.ItemsSource = dv;
```